# Error No Database Selected PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have class Called Database here's the syntax

```
<?php
class Database
{
 var $conn = null;
 var $config = array(
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'database' => '<dbname here>'
 );

 function __construct() {
    $this->connect();
    echo 'constructor database';
}

function connect() {
    if (is_null($this->conn)) {
        $db = $this->config;
        $this->conn = mysql_connect($db['hostname'], $db['username'], $db['password']);
        if(!$this->conn) {
            die("Cannot connect to database server"); 
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($db['database'])) {
            die("Cannot select database");
        }
    }
    return $this->conn;
}
```

}

i've include this database file to another php class let say it's authenticate.php

```
 include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/<project_name>/configuration/database.php';
```

which the class is:

```
class authenticate {

public function __construct() {
    $db = new Database();
    $db->connect();
}

public function auth($username, $password) {
    $password = $this->HASH($username, $password);
    $query = "SELECT username, password FROM mt_user WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
    $row = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_num_rows($row);
    if ($result != 1) {
        $status_login = "FALSE";
    } else
    if ($result == 1) {
        $status_login = "TRUE";
    }
    mysql_close();
    return $status_login;
}

public function getSalt($username) {
    $query = "SELECT salt FROM mt_user WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $salt = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $salt = $row['salt'];
    }
    mysql_close();
    return reset($salt);
}

public function HASH($username,$password){
    $salt = $this->getSalt($username);
    $output = sha1($salt.$password);
    return $output;
}

}

?>
```

i call the function to some view called login.php but it's throwing error on authenticate.php that "Cannot select database" or Cannot Connect to DB.

What's wrong with this authenticate or database.php files?

thank you.

Comment: include should use filesystem paths, not URLs, if you want to actually include the code

Comment: Have you verified the value of `$db['database']` at the time you call `mysql_select_db` (which is deprecated, by the way)?

Comment: @GolezTrol: yes i've check it. It's setup the right db.

Comment: This is not an answer but may help. The usage of the `var` keyword is deprecated. (It's the PHP4 way, didn't see this since years).. Use `private`, `protected` or `public` instead..

Comment: @hek2mgl thanks for your comment. i've changed it to public instead. I think this is simple problem. But i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/2536029

Answer (score 0):

tell mysql which resource to use

```
    if(!mysql_select_db($db['database'],$this->conn)) {
        die("Cannot select database");
```

also mysql_* is deprecated, before you go much further consider switching to mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: the error function is not in database class, it's on the authenticate class. I've found that the class cannot calling connect function in database class. how to call the function in authenticate class? is the constructor i made is correct?